# Conflict with same ID on different pages of site using Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, duplicates

I am making a mobile version of an existing site using query mobile. The site is hundreds of pages with established markup that works fine for the www version. The problem is that there are many instances of the same element ID on every page like #useername or #map or #photo. This is fine on www since each page loads independently so there is no conflict. In JQM, it looks like all the pages are somehow cached together and the code refers to the previous page. For example:

Page1.html

```
<div id="commonIdOnEveryPage">Page 1</div>
<a href="page2.html">Link</a>
<script>
alert($("#commonIdOnEveryPage").html());
</script>
```

Page2.html

```
<div id="commonIdOnEveryPage">Page 2</div>
<script>
alert($("#commonIdOnEveryPage").html());
</script>
```

After clicking the link from page 1 to go to page 2, the alert still shows "Page 1".

In this example, it would be easy change the id on the 2nd page, but in the actual site, there are hundreds of places on different pages where the same ID is used and the JS is thousands of linea long. Surely there is a way to make JQM compatible with this.

Comment: The problem is more than 1 page exists at a time on the DOM in jQuery Mobile. Try not using common id's, and instead make that a class and select it from activepage.

Comment: Unfortunately, not using jqm is a better solution than changing all the ids. This is a complex existing site that works perfectly. Also there are ids on dynamic pages like profile.php?id=1 which has #screenname then a link to profile.php?id=2 which also has #screenname.

Comment: See my edit for a solution with that in mind:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this code which seems to remove the previous page from the cache but preserve the back button and transition.

```
$('div').live('pagehide', function(event, ui) {
    $(event.target).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a common class instead, jQuery Mobile has more than one page in the DOM at a time, making your "unique" id's non-unique.

```
$(".ui-page-active .commonclass").html()
```

Edit:

If id's can't be unique, the next best thing would be:

```
$(".ui-page-active div[id=commonid]").html()
```

Comment: This might work, but it would be a huge task chaning all the ids to classes. Also have to make it work for the www site which doesn't have .ui-active-page.

Answer (score 2):

Tom Kinkaid's answer is a pro-tip.

Just cleaning it up a little to: 1) reduce overhead of removing every div from the cache, and 2) bring it up to date with new JQuery convention

```
$(document).on('pagehide', '.ui-page', function(event, ui) {
    $(event.target).remove();
});
```

Now, the cache is cleared of previous pages AND back button functionality is preserved.

Answer (score 1):

[By default](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) when you navigate to a page in JQM the framework loads the content of the page via ajax and attaches it to the `DOM`, so you are ending up with multiple id's per page. You can also [link to a page](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-links.html) so that it loads a page normally via `http` using either 'rel="external"`or`data-ajax="false"` which i think should solve your issue, you will need to make sure that the appropriate js files are linked in the head of each page though.

Comment: data-ajax=false works and is probably the quickest solution. Unfortunately, it loses the back button and the page transition loading animation.

Comment: I don't think that you should lose the back button (I tested it on my machine and it works). About the transition it says in the JQM docs that it  will load the page without the page transitions so i don't know if there is any way around that.

Answer (score 0):

Would using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('#commonIdOnEveryPage');
});
```

fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I create a unique string based on the time and append it to every id.

```
// unique string for use in DOM ids
$unique = str_replace(array(' ', '.') ,'_', microtime());
```

Then in the html output:

```
<div id="commonIdOnEveryPage<?php echo $unique; ?>">Page 2</div>
<script>
alert($("#commonIdOnEveryPage<?php echo $unique; ?>").html());
</script>
```